# Creating a Function if doesn't exist and alter the function if it already exists

Tags: sql, user-defined-functions, sql-server-2014, dynamic-sql

I am working on creating a scalar valued function but before creating it I would like to check if it exists and if it doesn't exist then create the function using dynamic script and then alter it normally. I got this working for a stored procedure but I couldn't do the same with a function.

my procedure is as follows

```
IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[region]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id,N'IsProcedure') = 1)
BEGIN
    EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement =  N' CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[region] AS BEGIN Print ''A'' END'
END
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[region](---)
AS
---
END
```

I tried to follow the same approach for a scalar valued function as follows

```
IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[region]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id,N'IsScalarFunction') = 1)
BEGIN
    EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N' CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[region]  AS RETURN 0'
```

GO

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.region(@dd datetime)
--
GO
```

But, above script threw me an error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.`

Comment: my apologies, I have edited my question and the error I listed nw is the actual error.

Comment: You have the word `AS` twice in your create function statement

Comment: it would be easier if you just drop the function if it exists and create afterwards

Comment: @Aツ dropping a function causes security issues as I have to manually grant permission to different users whose permissions are gone once a function is dropped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify parameters (even if none) and a return type for the function

```
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N' CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[region]() RETURNS VARCHAR AS  BEGIN RETURN ''A'' END'
```